# Can't register click event with a custom Preference

Tags: android, android-preferences

I've built a custom `Preference` that includes a `Button` for the `android:widgetLayout` field. I want to trigger a specific action when this button is pressed, but I'm having trouble getting a listener to pick up click events. Here is what I've tried:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {

        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        addPreferencesFromResource( R.xml.preference_account );

        Preference signOutPreference = findPreference( "sign_out" );
        signOutPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener( new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick( Preference preference ) {

                Log.i( TAG, "Click" );
                return false;
            }
        } );
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState ) {

        View root = super.onCreateView( inflater, container, savedInstanceState );
        root.findViewById( R.id.preference_signOut_Button ).setOnClickListener( new OnSignOutClickListener() );

        return root;
    }

    private class OnSignOutClickListener implements OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick( View v ) {

            Log.i( TAG, "Click" );
        }
    }
```

The `OnPreferenceClickListener` is never triggered when I click the button or the preference row, and the `onCreateView` implementation throws a `NullPointerException` when trying to find the button view.

How do I listen for when this button is clicked? For reference, here are the relevant XML files:

preference_account.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <Preference
        android:key="sign_out"
        android:persistent="false"
        android:summary="account@email.com"
        android:title="Signed in as:"
        android:widgetLayout="@layout/sign_out_button" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

sign_out_button.xml

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/preference_signOut_Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sign Out" />
```

**Edit:** I've found a solution using the `android:onClick` field of the button, but I still would like a solution using `Preference` if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try the below example:

```
class MyOnPreferenceClickListener implements OnPreferenceClickListener {
private Activity activity;
private static final String TAG = "ABCDEFGH...";

public MyOnPreferenceClickListener(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Click on Item " + preference.getKey());
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating @Sushanth Raghuthaman answer a little bit. This worked for me:

```
public class CustomPreference extends Preference implements OnPreferenceClickListener {

    public CustomPreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    }

    public CustomPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    }

    public CustomPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    }

    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        //Do something here...
        return true;
    }

}
```

The important line above is to register the preference click with itself *setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);*.